# Overriding all responses in AWS APIGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I have some HTTP API servers, lambda functions behind AWS APIGateway.
it's fine. just worked out of the box.

Assume that there is mainternance situation across over all servers, and all HTTP API endpoint MUST returns same response e.g) 500 MAINTERNANCE_IN_PROGRESS ..

How can I do that?
is there a feature in AWS APIGateway?

Answer (score 1):

AWS APIGateway doesn't provide way to return any response.

But you can connect all API Gateway with one route Lambda which handle all incoming request and based on url condition you can route to actual lambda function for further processing it.

```
API Gateway -> Route Lambda -> Task perform Lambda 1 

                            -> Task perform Lambda 2
```

So you need to modify only route Lambda for Maintenance mode.

Comment: is there any special configuration that should be done? if we have multiple lambdas, and multiple APIs - how can i use this in all of them?

Comment: You can use serverless framework which can manage all code at single place and easy to deploy. check out ref https://serverless.com/blog/node-rest-api-with-serverless-lambda-and-dynamodb/